# Equating set range1 to range2

Tags: excel, vba

Equating range1 to range2

Trying to make range2 values = range1 values
Range1 values defined for example: A1=2, A2=3, A3=8

```
Sub Test()

Set Rng1 = Range("A1:A3")

Set Rng2 = Range("B1:B3")

        Do Until Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value
            Rng2.Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)"
        Loop

End Sub
```

Rng2 will keep generating random number and loop until B1=2, B2=3, B3=8

For now keep getting runtime error 13. Please help

Comment: The result of _Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value_ is not a boolean.  That's the reason you get RTE 13. If that's the question because _[Please help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/6600940)_  is not a question which can be answered

Comment: With more than one cell Rng2.Value is producing an 2d array, same for Rng1.value

Comment: What in interesting way to set 2 ranges equal to each other. Why are you using `RANDBETWEEN`? I feel like there is some context missing here. If not, it seems that all you need to do is `Rng2.Value = Rng1.Value` and you are done

Comment: Urdearboy, choose randbetween otherwise the Do Until loop have nothing to loop for. Just for practicing VBA. Practice makes perfect

Comment: @JohnD5718 nice! This is exactly how I learned VBA a little over a year ago. My advice is to look at other questions here, try to answer them, and **read read read** other peoples solutions to see how yours attempt can be improved upon.

Comment: As an addition read the articles [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-articles/) and do the exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe OP wants do to do something like that

```
Sub Test()

Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, sngCell As Range
Dim eq As Long, i As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Rng1 = Range("A1:A3")
    Set Rng2 = Range("B1:B3")
    Rng2.Value = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)"

    eq = 0
    Do
        eq = 0
        Rng2.Calculate
        For Each sngCell In Rng1
            If sngCell.Value = sngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                eq = eq + 1
            End If
        Next
        i = i + 1
        If i > 10000 Then Exit Do  ' Just to avoid an endless loop
    Loop Until eq = 3

    Debug.Print "Loops: " & i

End Sub
```

Just put manually some integers between 1 and 9 into A1:A3 and the code puts some random integers into B1:B3. Then the code repeats putting random integers into B1:B3 until we have the same integers as in A1:A3. I have no idea what this is good for :-) Maybe OP wants to test some kind of probability functions like random variable or expected value (sorry, I do not know the correct english terms for it).

Here a version using arrays

```
Sub TestArray()
Dim v1(1 To 3) As Byte
Dim v2(1 To 3) As Byte

Dim eq As Byte
Dim i As Long, k As Long

    v1(1) = 6
    v1(2) = 4
    v1(3) = 2

    Do
        eq = 0
        For k = 1 To 3
            v2(k) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10)
        Next k
        For k = 1 To 3
            If v1(k) = v2(k) Then
                eq = eq + 1
            End If
        Next k
        i = i + 1
        If i > 10000 Then Exit Do
    Loop Until eq = 3
    Debug.Print "Loops: " & i

End Sub
```

Comment: I don’t know what this means but I upvoted anyway lol. This is a strange post and I’m really curious what OP is actually trying to do now after reading your solution

Comment: Thank you so much Storax. Sub Test(), it works.       Just want to test/ practice on the Do Until loop function. Paired it with randbetween, otherwise it won't be looping.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set ranges equal to each-other directly (`RangeX.Value = RangeY.Value`) and be done. Also wondering if there is some other context that was not shared though. The approach you tried to take makes me think that this isn't the full scope of your project

```
Sub (Test)

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B1:B3").Value = .Range("A1:A3").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks urdearboy for sharing. Actually is not a project. My purpose is to learn VBA and one way is to come up with some ideas/ problems and try come up with some working procedures. Thank you